# Laravel 5 - Mercurial recommended .hgignore

Tags: php, laravel, mercurial, laravel-5, hgignore

Using Laravel 5.x. or 5.1.x
What would be the basic recommended configuration for the .hgignore file?

Pulling from the .gitignore this is what I have:

```
syntax: glob
.env
.gitignore
.gitattributes
.idea
vendor/
node_modules/
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
```

Online I see for version 4 something about /bootstrap/compiled.php
Should I include /bootstrap/cache ?

Comment: Generally: everything which will frequently appear in the repository directories but shall not become part of it.

Comment: I found keeping the .gitignore file in some of the file structure creates an anchor, allowing for committing empty folders like /storage/cache/ /storage/sessions/ and  /storage/views/

Comment: mercurial only uses the .hgignore in its repository root folder (and your global one)

Answer (score 3):

I use negative lookahead to include the empty folder structure:

```
## Laravel specific
^\.env$
^vendor

## General
\.DS_Store$
[Tt]humbs\.db$

## Keep these folders, but ignore their content
^bootstrap/cache/(?!\.gitignore).+$
^storage/logs/(?!\.gitignore).+$
^storage/app/(?!\.gitignore).+$
^storage/framework/views/(?!\.gitignore).+$
^storage/framework/sessions/(?!\.gitignore).+$
^storage/framework/cache/(?!\.gitignore).+$
```

Comment: Hey @JannieT. I've tried you example, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I still see all my views under storage/framework/views for example, with a ? in front. I'd really like to get this working somehow. Any other idea why I would still see these files? Thanks

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia, do you perhaps have `syntax: glob` included? It might mess things up. Also, make sure you have a .gitignore file in that folder.

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia As a last resort, according to the docs, you can also specify a subfolder-specific ignore: "Subdirectories can have their own `.hgignore` settings by adding `subinclude:path/to/subdir/.hgignore` to the root `.hgignore`. But it is not necessary here. Mine works perfectly without it.

Comment: thanks, the syntax:glob was messing with it. It works fine now.